# Use of SQL analytic function from spark

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have SQL like below

```html
SELECT LIMIT, 
       COL1, 
       COL2, 
       COL3
 FROM   
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY COL5 DESC) AS LIMIT, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(COL_DATETIME,'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:mi:ss') COL1,
        CASE WHEN COL6 IN ('A', 'B') THEN A_NUMBER ELSE B_NUMBER END AS COL2, 
        COL3
 FROM   DBNAME.TABLENAME 
WHERE   COL7 LIKE ('123456%')  
  AND   COL_DATETIME BETWEEN 20150201000000 AND 20150202235959) X
```

I can execute it successfully from hive. But I want to execute it from spark. I have created a spark-sql-hive context like below

```html
scala> val sqlHContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
sqlHContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@71138de5
```

Then I tried to execute the above sql query like below

```html
sqlHContext.sql("SELECT LIMIT, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY COL5 DESC) AS LIMIT, FROM_UNIXTIME(COL_DATETIME,'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:mi:ss') COL1, CASE WHEN COL6 IN ('A', 'B') THEN A_NUMBER ELSE B_NUMBER END AS COL2, COL3 FROM DBNAME.TABLENAME WHERE  COL7 LIKE ('123456%')  AND COL_DATETIME BETWEEN 20150201000000 AND 20150202235959) X").collect().foreach(println)
```

But getting the error

```html
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Unsupported language features in query:


scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for ASTNode type: 882, text: TOK_WINDOWSPEC :
TOK_WINDOWSPEC 1, 90,98, 339
  TOK_PARTITIONINGSPEC 1, 91,97, 339
    TOK_ORDERBY 1, 91,97, 339
      TOK_TABSORTCOLNAMEDESC 1, 95,97, 339
        TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 95,95, 339
          CALL_DATETIME 1, 95,95, 339
" +
         
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.nodeToExpr(HiveQl.scala:1261)
```

It looks like analytic function is not supported. I am using spark version 1.3.0; hive version 1.1.0 and hadoop version 2.7.0

Is there any other way this can be achieved from spark?

Comment: Can this be achieved by using different spark commands and considering the table data in a file

Answer (score 1):

Window functions are supported as of Spark 1.4.0. There are still some limitations, e.g. ROWS BETWEEN is not yet supported. For an example have a look at this blog post on [Spark window functions](http://sonra.io/window-functions-aka-analytic-functions-in-spark/).